# Web Page - Chrome Extension Communication

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The communication, I mean (chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener) between a Web Page and a Chrome Extension every second is too much?

Can it saturate the web page, or Chrome? If yes, what would be a good threshold for this type of communication?

Comment: Please share your existing code implementation. Have you went through [Sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage)?

Comment: Why do you need to send a message every second?  The recommended approach would be to send a message only when needed (because something changed).  And for long lived message sessions (which this would be), you'd want to use a port.

Comment: Is important to maintain constant communication between the extension and the website. How can I use a port, or implement it, do you have a snippet?